# Basket equity swap

Tags: equities, swaps

What are the advantages of buying basket equity swaps derivative compared to single equity swap? Will correlation play a role in basket equity swap?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correlation will play an indirect role.  Begin by noting that, if correlation is 100%, then your basket swap will behave the same as a swap on a single equity (from a modeling point of view).  Thus your risk-management systems and derivatives will care about the correlation.  For pure valuation of the swap, there's no role for correlation.   Valuation is basically just mark-to-market.

Generally, equity swaps are used to trade in long-short positions that are unavailable or impractical from a regulatory point of view.  For example, you might be avoiding dividend taxes or trading foreign securities.  If you have a position that you intend to treat as a unit, comprised of a basket of securities, it makes sense to combine the whole thing into one swap to keep transaction costs low.

Note that basket *options* are considered correlation plays.